# Dual GPU Setup: Xorg on Intel Integrated GPU, NVIDIA GPU for Gaming

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia, opensuse, xorg

I recently purchased a new laptop and installed openSUSE Tumbleweed on it. The laptop has an Intel Core i5 processor with integrated graphics and an NVIDIA 3050 Ti. My goal is to configure Xorg to run on the integrated GPU and disable the NVIDIA GPU when it's not required. To achieve this, I used `prime-select` to set the offload mode by running the command `sudo prime-select offload`.

However, I encountered a problem where Xorg is still running on the NVIDIA GPU. When I checked the output of `nvidia-smi`, I received the following information:

```
Sun May 28 10:00:02 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.116.04   Driver Version: 525.116.04   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8     6W /  30W |      5MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3246      G   /usr/bin/Xorg.bin                   4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Additionally, when I checked the task manager, it indicated that Xorg should not be running on the NVIDIA GPU. I have examined the `xorg.conf` file located at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and it contains the following configuration:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen "intel"
    Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

# needed for NVIDIA PRIME Render Offload
Section "Device"
  Identifier "nvidia"
  Driver "nvidia"
  BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
```

I apologize if any necessary information is missing. Please let me know if you require any additional details. This is my first time working with a graphics card, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see an Intel GPU listed with `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`? Any line referring to the `nodesetting` driver in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log, `?

Comment: Yes, I see `OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)` . Here all lines containing `modesetting`:

[    23.352] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.352] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    23.352] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.352]  compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 1.21.1
[    23.352]  Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.352]  ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
(here it loads "nvidia")
[    23.355] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms

Comment: Could you also run `prime-run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`, and check whether it outputs the NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: OpenSUSE tumbleweed doesn't have a `prime-run` command but I did set the environment variables. Here the output: `OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2`

Comment: What this equivalent to prime_run returns? `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`

Comment: It was `OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2`, as mentioned in my previous comment. But this doesn't matter anymore since we found the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I simply added GPUDevice "intel" to the `xorg.conf` file!

The `GPUDevice` option [in the `Screen` section of the `xorg.conf` file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.html#screen%20section) specifies which GPU should be used as the primary GPU by the X server.
By setting `GPUDevice "intel"`, you are instructing the X server to use the integrated Intel GPU as the primary device.

In a [PRIME offload setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME), the primary GPU (in this case, the Intel GPU) is used for running the X server and most applications, while the secondary GPU (the NVIDIA GPU) is used only for specific applications that require more graphics power.
By setting the Intel GPU as the primary device, you are ensuring that the X server and most applications run on the Intel GPU, which is likely why you are no longer seeing any processes running on the NVIDIA GPU.

Note, the NVIDIA driver keeps the GPU ready to handle requests for GPU acceleration, so it might not go into a low power state even when it is not actively being used.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right! I wonder why I never saw anything about this flag in online tutorials about setting up PRIME Offload?! But thanks anyway! I will give you the 100 premium in 10 hours!

Answer (score 0):

OHHHHHH, YESSSSS. I SOLVED IT! I simply added `GPUDevice "intel"` to the xorg.conf file! Now there are no proceses running on the NVIDIA GPU! It doesn't go into low power state but I think I will figure it out.

Thanks to @VonC! I saw it in the logs that it used nvidia as the GPUDevice.

Edit:
I eventually got the PRIME offloading working thanks to this tutorial: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME

Comment: Good catch, well done.